# Creating google groups programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I need to create a **google group** using my google app engine application. Please guide me where should i look for info regarding this. Where should i start my learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups can be created with the [groups.insert()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#create_group) API call which is part of the Admin SDK Directory API. Note that it's only possible for Google Apps Administrators to programatically create Google Groups within their domain, non-Google Apps accounts cannot create groups via this API.

Comment: by reading developers doc what i came to know is that, groups can be created only for our own domains not for appspot.com applications.

my requirement is im letting a user to create a group and add members to his group.. How can i create such a group. Is tat possible.. if not possibe do i need to maintain those groups in my Database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for creating groups outside of a Google Apps domain you control.

Answer from Jay is the best starting point if you decide to manage this within a domain.